# State change not happening in conjunction with $http post

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

For some reason, I cannot get the state to change when I make a login $http post to my local server.

Controller:

```
    $scope.login = function(user){
        $http.post('/api/v1/user/login', user)
            .success(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
                authToken.setToken(data);
                $state.go('user.exercises');
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                $scope.status = data;
            });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login(user)">
            Log In
        </button>
        <p class="text-center">
            <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

ionic.project:

```
"proxies": [
    {
        "path": "/api/v1",
        "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:5000/api/v1"
    }
]
```

config.xml

```
<description>
    An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
  Ionic Framework Team
</author>
<content src="index.html"/>

//important
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
</feature>
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with the way I have it set up to use my server or if it is an actually ionic and ui-router problem. This works with my web version.

**UPDATE:**

It works if there are two $state.gos. Not one or the other. It needs to have both. This doesn't make any sense.

```
$scope.login = function(user){
        $state.go('user.exercises');
        $http.post('/api/v1/user/login', user)
            .success(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
                authToken.setToken(data);
                $state.go('user.exercises');
            })
            .error(function(data, status){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.status = data;
            });
    };
```

Comment: If you're sure the api call is succesful then i would think its your routes with ui-router. should be able to check the console and see if it is throwing an error about not being able to find the state

Comment: @teliren I'm getting data back from the login, so it's definitely successful. The route is also correct because I was working on it before the login and if I take out the post from the function, it will change to the correct state. It's a conundrum.

Comment: Where in the app is this `$http` call?

Comment: @charlietfl It's local server that runs the web version of this app. Just finds the user and sends the json back.

Comment: right but where is that code block? controller, routing resolve etc?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't have a problem with that. It working properly and is sending a JSON object back. The problem is with the view not changing.